# Rails controller and permissions for users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, controller, action

I'm stuck with a very simple Rails problem.

I have a blog controller which has these lines:

```
skip_before_action :check_admin, only: [:index, :show], raise: false

...

private
...

def check_admin
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user && current_user.admin?
end
```

I want the behavior to be the following:

if a user is not logged in or is logged in and its role is not admin, and tries to access other actions rather than :index and :show, it should redirect to the root path.

But right now, it shows the user login page for every action when a user is not logged in, whereas it allows every action for any logged in user, even not admin ones.

I am using Devise and CanCanCan. My `ability.rb` looks like this:

```
def initialize(user)
  can :read, :all                   # allow everyone to read everything
  if user && user.admin?
    can :access, :rails_admin       # only allow admin users to access Rails Admin
    can :dashboard                  # allow access to dashboard
    can :manage, :all
  end
end
```

Where am I failing?

**EDIT**: I changed the action call in the controller to this:

```
before_action :check_admin, except: [:index, :show]
```

Now, the desired behavior is showing for logged users, whereas for unlogged users it is still redirecting to the user login page for every action including index and show.

**EDIT 2**: I have `before_action :authenticate_user!` in `application_controller.rb` while some other controllers are set with `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index]`. But this shouldn't interfer with the blog controller in my opinion...

Also, I have the following in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  ### Popular gems integration

  ## == Devise ==
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
```

Comment: That is a really egregious abuse of the ternary operator. Why not just `redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user && current_user.admin?`

Comment: @meagar I tried your line and it yields the same result

Comment: That wasn't meant to be an answer, just commentary

Comment: I edited the question with your line anyway ;)

Comment: do you have before_action :authenticate_user! ? in your controller or any other devise authentication calls? (including in application controller)

Comment: @Gaston I don't have it in my blog controller but in others, see edit 2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have before_action :authenticate_user! in your application controller.  if you see your controller definition,:

```
class BlogController< ApplicationController
```

'<' operator means BlogController inherits from ApplicationController, therefore all your controllers (except those with skip_before_action) will require authentication.

you'll need

```
Class BlogController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index, :show]
```

Comment: So there's no way to tell the controller to redirect to the root path for unlogged users, isn't it? Adding your line actually does redirect them to the login path

Comment: yes there is, with my answer, all actions in blogs controller(except index and show) will be redirected to the root_path for un-logged users. It should be working though, as you can read here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Comment: can you explain how? I added your line at the top of my controller, so that the check_admin action filter follows that. But if unlogged users go to a forbidden action, the login path shows up, instead of the root path.